# rm all files to the right of "==" printed on the screen

Tags: shell-script

I have a script that prints:

```
dhcp-18-189-47-44:CE06_getting_new_fit myname$ ./find-duplicate-structures.sh custom_structures new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_00*
../CE05-structures_recombined/enum-00135/POSCAR.ideal == new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0011 (RMSD = 1.15475827927e-06, max. displacement = 1.41428428091e-06)
../CE05-structures_recombined/enum-00146/POSCAR.ideal == new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0022 (RMSD = 1.16051714442e-06, max. displacement = 1.42835572031e-06)
../CE05-structures_recombined/enum-00150/POSCAR.ideal == new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0027 (RMSD = 3.40556388834e-16, max. displacement = 6.04819551804e-16)
../CE05-structures_recombined/enum-00151/POSCAR.ideal == new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0027 (RMSD = 4.01650747941e-16, max. displacement = 5.4726685759e-16)
../CE05-structures_recombined/enum-00163/POSCAR.ideal == new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0037 (RMSD = 1.99174954223e-06, max. displacement = 2.44948961046e-06)
```

In internally the script looks like:

```
dirs=$1
shift
while read dir
do
if [ -f $dir/POSCAR.ideal ]
then poscar=$dir/POSCAR.ideal
else poscar=$dir/POSCAR
fi
mg match --just-match $poscar $@
done < $dirs

exit 0
```

The printing occurs at the line mg match --just-match $poscar $@

However, in my practice, I would like to remove everything to the right "==", i.e.:

```
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0011
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0022
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0027
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0037
```

How could I automate this process in shell script? Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try parsing your program's output with `sed` and executing the commands:

```
$(./YOUR_PROGRAM | sed s/^.*==/rm/ | sed s/\ \(.*//)
```

will execute (from your example)

```
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0011
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0022
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0027
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0027
rm new_GS_calculation/selected/POSCAR_0037
```

---

`sed` works with the following syntax:

```
sed s/string1/string2/
```

which replaces `string1` with `string2`.

What is happening here is:

1. the output of your program is sent to `sed` with the first pipe `|`
2. for each line of output,`sed` everything from the beginning (marked
   by `^`) to the `==` sign and replaces it with the letters `rm`. It
   sends the rest of the line into another `sed` call with a second
   pipe
3. `sed` now looks for and removes a space followed by a left
   parenthesis, denoted by `\ \(`, and anything that follows, denoted
   by `.*`.
4. the whole command is wrapped in `$(...)` so bash executes the
   output, which in this case a string of `rm new_GS_calculation/...`
   commands.

Comment: great... but for the convenience of user, do you think it is possible to add into the shell script itself? Thank you

Comment: You can just put the command in `command.sh` and execute it with `./command.sh`.

Comment: In this command $(./YOUR_PROGRAM | sed s/^.*==/rm/ | sed s/\ \(.*//), did you miss some parenthesis? ... Oh! I see from your explanation that no parenthesis is missed!!!

Comment: sed has been always a mystery to me, and you really explained it very well!!! Thank you.